# Regex remove trailing e (except for all 2 and 3 letter words)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to write a simple regular expression that will remove the trailing 'e' character in all words except 2 and 3 letter words in a string.
The following solution will find the words properly but will match full words and not just 'e'.

```
/\b\w{2,}e\b/
```

I am unable to combine proposed solution with lookahead groups (using '(?=)') to work properly.

Comment: Could [this](https://regex101.com/r/gKbrDj/2) be helpfull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind:

```
(?<=\w\w\w)e\b
```

Comment: regexpal returns an error "lookbehind is not supported in JS", however, I tried running it in node and it works.

Comment: @nejc: At this date, lookbehind is not supported only in IE and Safari, see: https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: Could we use repetition ammoun '{}' instead of \w\w\w ? If we would try to match longer words (say length 15+) the code would get ugly...

Comment: @Nejc: Yes, of course, you can write `\w{3}` or any number of letters, it's strictly the same meaning.

Comment: I tried, but its not working https://regex101.com/r/11HFUh/12

Comment: @nejc: you've made a typo, remove the backslash before the opening curly brace

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the training e chars in a word except for the 1st, second or third char, you could capture 1-3 word chars, then match as least as possible word chars and match the trailing e chars.

```
\b(\w{1,3}\w*?)e*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZBJxsF/1)

In the replacement use group 1.

To remove a single e, change `e*` to `e?`

```js
[
  "theeeeeeeee",
  "the",
  "te",
  "ee",
  "eee",
  "eeee",
  "abcdefeee",
  "ehteheeee",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/\b(\w{1,3}\w*?)e*\b/, "$1")))
```

If you don't have to take the word boundary at the start into account, you could capture 3 word chars and match a single e at the end.

```
(\w{3})e\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9NRX6/1)

```js
[
  "thee",
  "the",
  "te",
  "ee",
  "eee",
  "eeee",
  "abcdefeee",
  "ehteheeee",
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/(\w{3})e\b/, "$1")))
```

Comment: @Mandy8055 The assertion in `(?=.{4,})e+$` runs on every position. Before the `feee`, the assertion is true, but it can not match `e+$` as there is still an `f`